# How to change currency from euro to dollars in Google AdSense?

Tags: google, google-adsense

In my Google AdSense account all earnings are shown in euros. When I receive check it has $96 in it, what is equivalent of 70 euros. It would be better to receive check for round amount of money. For euro - it is 70, for dollars - it is $100. But earnings in euros are send in dollars too. So I would like to change the currency to dollars. I did not find in AdSense options and on forums how to change it to dollars.

**Does anyone know how to change currency from euro to dollars in Google AdSense?**

Or at least how can I send (order) checks manually and not automatically (after achieving 70 euros or $100)?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to change the reporting currency of your account once you've set it. If you'd like to switch to another new reporting currency, you'll need to [close your current account](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?answer=9914) and open a new one.